# Constrained Optimization in R using constOptim

Tags: r, optimization, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am trying to find the maximum values of this objective function:

**f(x1,x2,x3) = 1300x1 + 600x2 + 500x3**

subject to the following constraints

**300x1 + 150x2 + 100x3 <= 4,000**

**90x1 + 30x2 + 40x3 <= 1,000**

**x1 <= 5**

**x1, x2, x3 >= 0**

Below is the code I am using, which is not returning the values I'm looking for. The outputs for the variables are 9.453022e-12 3.272252e-12 5.548419e-14 and the total value is -1.428002e-08.

I'm new to R. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
f=function(x) -(1300*x[1]+600*x[2]+500*x[3]) # minimize -f(x,y,z) 

inequalities=function(x){ #define the ineqaulities function
  h=0
  h[1]=-(300*x[1]+150*x[2]+100*x[3]-4000)
  h[2]=-(90*x[1]+30*x[2]+40*x[3]-1000)
  h[3]=-(1*x[1]+0*x[2]+0*x[3]-5)
  return(h)}

g=function(x){ #x,y,z > 0
  h=0
  h[1]=x[1]
  h[2]=x[2]
  h[3]=x[3]
  return(h)}

p0=c(0,0,0) #give the starting point

y=constrOptim.nl(p0,f,hin=inequalities,heq=g); 

print(y$par)
print(y$value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

```
heq: a vector function specifying equality constraints such that heq[j] = 0 for all j
```

So the lower bounds `x[1],x[2],x[3] >= 0` you are trying to specify, are actually interpreted as `x[1],x[2],x[3] = 0`. Hence the solution:  9.453022e-12, 3.272252e-12 5.548419e-14. Your lower bounds need to be incorporated in `hin`.

Note that there are better, linear solvers for linear problems. Passing on a linear problem to a non-linear solver is not optimal.

Comment: Thank you for the response Erwin. I've used the Excel Solver tool to find the values I need, but am wanting to learn how to do this in R. How can I best incorporate the lower bounds in hin? And what other linear solvers do you recommend? Thanks again.

Comment: (1) Just treat the bounds as inequality constraints. (2) LP (linear programming) solvers are readily available for R.